# Is a non-orientable surface a kind of manifold?

Tags: manifolds

An example of a non-orientable surface is the Moebius Strip. Iam just curious whether it is indeed a manifold by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: a Möbius band is a manifold.

There are both orientable and non-orientable manifolds. The [Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle) and the [real projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) are two other examples of [non-orientable surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability).

The definition of a manifold is a local one. The definition of orientability is a global one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an open manifold. Orientability has nothing to do with it...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as a manifold or as a $\partial$-manifold, of two cases.